# How to solve location permissions policy

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

**Hi team,**

I have concerns regarding the location permissions policy issue
it's been a long month solving this problem, but I
still experience rejection for these errors.

**Google Response:**

> (Bundle Version: 7) is not compliant with the Location Permissions policy, or we were unable to review and verify your in-app experience for compliance with this policy.

> Feature not eligible for background location access Based on your declaration, we determined that you can use foreground location access instead of access to location in the background to function.
> Please remove access to location in the background from your app, and/or use foreground location access instead. For help on using foreground location access instead, please see our developer documentation.

What I have done so far first to remove the access background location in the android manifest xml file,

Android Manifest Setup:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Could you append the permissions part of your manifest.xml for us to see how you set-up the background location access?

Comment: Hi @WilliamBrochensquejunior I add manifest xml setup. Thank you